Exact meaning of the mass $M$ in the Kerr metric event horizon?
Posting this as I have so far not been able to find a straightforward answer to the following question. The formula for the outer event horizon of a kerr black hole is given by the following equation:
$$
r_+ = \frac{GM}{c^2}\left(1+\sqrt{1-\frac{J^2c^2}{M^4G^2}}\right)
$$
Where $J$ is the angular momentum of the black hole. My question is this: does the mass $M$ in this equation correspond to the irreducible mass of the black hole? Or does it correspond to the total mass equivalent of the black hole when the rotational mass-energy is included?
Mathematically speaking, does $M = M_{irr}$? Or does $M = \sqrt{M_{irr}^2 + \frac{J^2c^2}{4M_{irr}^2G^2}}$?
Edit: I should also mention that, despite my best efforts, I've yet to come across a textbook that answers this explicitly, with the distinction seemingly being taken for granted. Even when talking to others informally about this, there does not seem to be a consensus (there are already answers/comments in this thread stating opposing viewpoints). So if anyone has an answer, a source would be greatly appreciated if possible, thanks!

The M is the rest mass.Otherwise it would be ambiguous to put angular momentum,charge and mass in the same equations since they all contribute to the stress-energy tensor of the black hole.

Related (but unfortunately unanswered): If a massive sphere spins faster and faster, will a black hole appear?.

Thanks for the response, however, I'm not sure I entirely agree that it would be ambiguous. Let's imagine the M did correspond to the total mass-energy. In this case, the formula for the event horizon would now have an M_irr term and a J term (which would be inherently dependent on M_irr and the angular velocity of the black hole). You could hypothetically imagine speeding up this angular velocity while leaving M_irr constant. This would only increase J, and thus change the event horizon radius accordingly in a non-ambiguous way would it not?

@Scott Mass-energy is not the only thing which contributes to the stress-energy tensor and it would be weird to referring to M as the mass energy when you have c's in the equation.Usually a formula tries to make things simple so if it were mass-energy they would just use rest mass * c^2.

Also in this case E=mc^2 no longer holds bcs the black hole is rotating so it would be even more weird.

But E=mc^2 only holds in general when m is the relativistic mass, (the expanded equation is E=gammam_0c^2, where m_0 is the rest mass) which inherently takes the energy of motion into account. If anything, this would be an argument in support of the M in the Kerr metric being the total mass-energy after including the rotational energy?

@Scott no E=mc^2 doesnt hold here because the spinning black hole has angular momentum.The correct formula is E^2 = m^2c^4+p^2c^2 and since p is not 0 E=mc^2 is wrong.E=mc^2 holds for something without momentum and it isnt related to motion it is the inherent energy a object with mass m possess due to its mass.

My understanding is that E = mc^2 IS a general relation that holds in all cases as long as all components of the "mass" are taken into account (rest mass, motion, etc). It is an equivalent representation of the well-known Einstein dispersion relation you provided, so I think we'll have to agree to disagree on this particular point. That being said, if you have any specific sources that specify that the mass M in the Kerr metric is indeed the rest mass, then I will gladly concede! (I've been having a lot of trouble finding any thus the post)

@Scott then you are wrong.Einstein didnt even write E=mc^2 he wrote E^2=m^2c^4+p^2c^2 E=mc^2 is just famous bcs it looks that he simplified a extremely complicated topic,blame the media ,unless you believe me,believe Fermilab https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BhG_QZl8WVY&list=PLCfRa7MXBEspw_7ZSTVGCXpSswdpegQHX.

I think we might be talking past each other here because like I said, I'm well aware of the Einstein dispersion relation in its original form  E = m0*c^2 is a special case of it, I understand that. But E = mc^2 is an EQUIVALENT way of writing E^2 = (pc)^2 + (m0c^2)^2, when E and m are the total energy and total mass respectively. In any case, this is probably getting too lengthy for the comment section now so if you'd like continue talking in chat let me know!

@RootGroves “Einstein didnt even write $E=mc^2$ he wrote $E^2=m^2c^4+p^2c^2$” - Dirac wrote this in 1928, not Einstein.

For the equation, you provided, it is in fact the real Mass of the Black Hole.
You can derive it yourself by setting the $g_{tt}$ component of the Kerr-Metric to 0 and solving for the radius.
Stealing from Wikipedia, you have $g_{tt} = 1 - \frac{\frac{2GM}{c^2} r}{r^2+\frac{J^2}{M^2c^2}}$. By setting this to zero, you can get your outer and inner horizon.

Appreciate the response but I don't think this really answers the question unfortunately

Okay. I am still not sure if I understand it, but I try.
Do you know the No-Hair Theorem? It states that any Black Hole can be decribed by just the mass, the charge and the spin.

@Ken OP doesnt understand correctly Mass-Energy equivalence so I dont think there is any point , not to be rude but thats the truth.

@RootGroves I understand mass-energy equivalence just fine. I have plenty of training in this field. Please refer to the following wikipedia article (which provides plenty of sources) on how E = mc^2 is an equivalent expression of the Einstein dispersion relation: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy%E2%80%93momentum_relation.... In particular the "connection to E=mc^2" section.

But E=mc^2 IS NOT the complete formula its a soecial case.Have you even bothered to watch the playist I linked you in?I dont want to be rude but you have a inflated ego and you are really annoying.Literally anyone can write anything in Wikipedia while the videos are from the Fermilab.

I have seen that video yes. To be honest I'm not sure you're reading my comments either since I have explicitly stated multiple times I'm well aware of the general Einstein dispersion relation and how it connects to the special case of p = 0, and the more general case where that is not so. I'll state it one last time: E=mc^2 is EQUIVALENT to E^2 = (pc)^2 + (m0c^2)^2, when E and m are the total energy and total mass respectively. Not sure what else I can say at this point, nor how anything I've said is a sign of an inflated ego, so I'll just leave it that. Thanks for the responses anyways!

@Scott (γ-1)mc^2 is not always equal to pc tho.Take the case of a photon.The first part is 0 while the 2nd clearly isnt 0.

From ${M}=\sqrt{M_{i r r}^{2}+\frac{J^{2}c^{2}}{4M_{i r r}^{2}G^{2}}}$ you can see, that the mass of the Kerr black hole increases, the bigger $J$ is. If the Kerr black hole is spun down to $J=0$, it is left with its irreducible mass and corresponds to a Schwarzschild black hole. Now, since the curvature of the spacetime depends on the total mass of the Kerr black hole, it is mandatory to use ${M}=\sqrt{M_{i r r}^{2}+\frac{J^{2}c^{2}}{4M_{i r r}^{2}G^{2}}}$ in the formula of $r_{+}=\frac{G M}{c^{2}}\left(1+\sqrt{1-\frac{J^{2}c^{2}}{M^{4}G^{2}}}\right)$, since $M_{irr}$ is the mass of the Kerr black hole only in the case of $J=0$.

thanks for the answer. Any chance you might have a source that explicitly states that this is indeed the case?

I think you can look up any introductory book to General Relatvity, where they talk about the Kerr black hole and irreducible mass. Since they use the same letter $M$ for the total mass ${M}=\sqrt{M_{i r r}^{2}+\frac{J^{2}c^{2}}{4M_{i r r}^{2}G^{2}}}$ and the position of the event horizon $r_{+}=\frac{G M}{c^{2}}\left(1+\sqrt{1-\frac{J^{2}c^{2}}{M^{4}G^{2}}}\right)$, it indicates that it is the same $M$.

Unfortunately, the textbooks I've looked into do not explicitly state if M is the irreducible mass or total mass - the distinction seems to be taken for granted. Even when talking to others informally, I have yet to come across a consensus (there is already a commenter in this very thread stating it's the rest/irreducible mass). While I do agree that it would make the most sense if it were the total mass, I was really hoping someone may be able to provide a source to confirm these suspicions!
